# Laravel - How to connect with sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, macos, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm working in a OS X and i install a virtual box with sql server, i set the network virtual box to connect.

[image]

In mac i install the freetds and if i do this command it connect:
[image]

The laravel connection is this:

```
'dbname' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '2222'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'dbname'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'xpto'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'xpto1234'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

When i run laravel i have the error `could not find driver`.

In `phpinfo()` i have mssql extension but don't have `sqlsrv`.
[image]

To make the installations I was guided by this link:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/529/como-utilizar-o-freetds-com-mamp-no-mac-os

What is the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: to be clear you have sqlserver and not MySql server right?

Comment: Yes. I don't know what i have to do more to this works... @keaner

Answer (score 0):

Are you set your app from .env file?
if you dont know where is in your root app folder.

Comment: I'm not using .env file to setting the connection to database. Just in /config/database.php . I have to use multiple databases. It works well before but i have to clean my mac and install all already but know this is not work. @Johanng1993

Comment: when you clean your mac, you saved all your project folder with vendor folder?